# system of equation with absolute symbole containing an under expression

Tags: equations

In fact, I want to know how can I write this system of equation below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible trick to use is `aligned` that frees from quirks about the size of the fractions and allows for easier distancing the two parts than `array`.

I added some negative space before the second = to reflect what's done in the original image, experiment the best value for you. I also removed the unneeded parentheses in the denominators.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
& \frac{k_{i\omega}}{k_{p\omega}}=2\pi\cdot\frac{1}{2}
\\[1ex]
& \biggl|
    \frac{k_{p\omega}s+k_{i\omega}}{s}\frac{1}{\tau s+1}\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\Gamma}s+1}
  \biggr|_{S=j\cdot 2\pi}\mspace{-10mu}=1
\end{aligned}
\right.
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note how my usage of `aligned` differs from what has already been proposed.

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

This produces expressions of this sort.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\left\{\begin{array}{@{}l}
 \dfrac{k_{i\omega}}{k_{p\omega}}=2\pi\times\frac{1}{2}\\[1em]
 \left|
  \dfrac{(k_{p\omega}s+k_{i\omega})}{s}\dfrac{1}{(\tau s+1)}
  \dfrac{1}{(\frac{1}{\Gamma}s+1)}
 \right|_{S=j\cdot2\pi}=1
\end{array}\right.
\]

\[
\left\{\begin{aligned}
 \dfrac{k_{i\omega}}{k_{p\omega}}&=2\pi\times\frac{1}{2}\\
 \left|
  \frac{(k_{p\omega}s+k_{i\omega})}{s}\frac{1}{(\tau s+1)}
  \frac{1}{(\frac{1}{\Gamma}s+1)}
 \right|_{S=j\cdot2\pi}&=1
\end{aligned}\right.
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

As they stand, these equations seem to be a bit odd, though. The brace does not appear to have any real purpose, the reader may wonder about the relation between lowercase and uppercase `s`, etc., but in a document with explanations this may make more sense.

Comment: thank you very much